# Which approach is the best to calculate a running total

Tags: c#, sql, architecture, sql-server-2012

This evening I've been pondering about how to bet tackle a problem of a running total. I’m using C# with Entity Framework and SQL Server 2012 to develop an application that can analyze my bank transactions.

In the database, I’ve created a table `Payment`, which contains the following properties:

```
PaymentDate, FromAccountId, ToAccountId, Amount
```

The latter property, `Amount`, is always positive; the direction of the transaction should be determined from the properties `FromAccountId` and `ToAccountId`.

Now, I have to be able to calculate the running total at any given time. For instance, by subtracting the running total at the beginning of the month from that at the end of the month, I can deduce the balance for a specific account. Calculating this running total will play a significant role in the application, so a single calculation cannot take too long.

I’ve come up with 4 strategies to calculate this running total:

1. Use stored procedure where the time and the account are input parameters.
2. Calculate the running total in my application (since I’m using Entity Framework, the calculation will de facto take place in the database)
3. Creating a table `RunningTotal` and update it for every transaction. The downside to this approach is that I have to keeping this table up to date myself, i.e. more business logic.
4. Similar to option 3, but then use a view that is based on the Payment table. This way, I should have to deal with extra business logic.

The thing is, I cannot make up my mind which approach is the best. What are your thoughts?

Comment: All these options have pros & cons. As such, this is a matter of opinion, so it's off-topic for [so]. One option you haven't considered is a variation of option 3, but use database triggers to update the running total. That's probably what I'd use, but it all depends...

Comment: For SQL Server **2012**, I would look at option #1 in order to be able to use the new `LAG` and `LEAD` T-SQL functions which will allow you to calculate running totals very easily. See [Intro to LAG and LEAD](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/) for an explanation

Comment: See [this](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) and [this](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/grouped-running-totals) for performance comparisons of various techniques, including those introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Since I'm by no means a t-sql guru, the information you provided me about the features of Sql Server 2012 were very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to calculate a running total in SQL Server 2012 (and Oracle and Postgres and DB2 and Teradata) is to use the cumulative sum function.  Here is a basic example:

```
select PaymentDate, FromAccountId, ToAccountId, Amount,
       sum(Amount) over (partition by FromAccountId, ToAccountId
                         order by PaymentDate
                        ) as cumAMount
from payments;
```

I suspect that you want something slightly different, to add amounts from-->to and to subtract to-->from.  You can also do this, but the syntax is more complicated:

```
select PaymentDate, FromAccountId, ToAccountId, Amount,
       sum((case when FromAccountId < ToAccountId then Amount
                 else -Amount
            end
           )
          ) over
           (partition by (case when FromAccountId < ToAccountId then FromAccountId else ToAccountId end),
                         (case when FromAccountId < ToAccountId then ToAccountId else FromAccountId end)

                         order by PaymentDate
                        ) as cumAMount
from payments;
```

This is just putting a sign in front of the amount, depending on the direction.  It then aggregates such that (FromAccountId, ToAccountId) go together, regardless of the direction of the payment.